# How can I ensure the correct exit code is passed from an executing postbuild app to Visual Studio so I don't get an MSB3073 error?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

VS2017 Enterprise, .Net 4.6.2:

I am launching a small console app as a project postbuild event. The console app explicitly sets Environment.Exitcode to 0 when it completes, and also returns that value. I've tried doing this as a Visual Studio post-build event, and also by defining it as a target in the csproj file for the project. However in both cases Visual Studio reports the app exits with code -1, so the build 'fails' with an error when it shouldn't.

Console app code:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
//do the work
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (int)ExitCode.GeneralError; //-999
    }
    Environment.ExitCode = (int)ExitCode.Success; //0
    return (int)ExitCode.Success;
}
```

Here's my Target in the csproj file in question:

```html
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" >
    <PropertyGroup>
      <CodeCheckerExe Condition=" '$(CodeCheckerExe)'=='' ">$(SolutionDir)..\Tools\CodeChecker\CodeChecker.exe</CodeCheckerExe>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
          <CodeCheckArgs>&quot;&quot;$(SolutionDir)&quot; stats tests listmissingcopyright</CodeCheckArgs>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(CodeCheckerExe) $(CodeCheckArgs)"/>   </Target
```

By attaching a debugger to the console application I have proved that it receives the correct arguments in the expected format, and completes successfully without error, and yet MSBuild still reports that it exits with an exit code of -1:

```
The command "C:\VSSource\pathtoconsoleapp" "filepath" stats tests listmissingcopyright" exited with code -1.
```

How can I ensure the correct app exitcode is passed to Visual Studio, so Visual Studio doesn't report an error when the app has actually completed successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I added an IgnoreExitCode attribute to the Exec element in the Target. That at least stopped the wrong exit code from failing the build.

eg

```
<Exec Command="$(CodeCheckerExe) $(CodeCheckArgs)" IgnoreExitCode="True"/>
```